# How to draw a vertical bar on every 4th space in Vim?

Tags: vim, indentation, highlight

I'd like (g)Vim to draw a pipe symbol `|` on each 4th space of indentation to show something like vertical indentation line.

I found this plugin: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=628,
but it works only with tab characters, and I'm using spaces for indentation.

My `.vimrc` contains:

```
set ts=4
set sw=4
set expandtab 
set softtabstop=4
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to display indentation guides in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could simply highlight every fourth space. Although it might look
a bit hackish, is is simpler and quite effective. Please take a look
at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim/2166979#2166979) to the question “[Is it possible to display
indentation guides in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim)” where I lay out the technique
in full detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **my** plugin: https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine.

It completely satisfies your requirements. It displays a thin vertical line, and not a fat vertical line like http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.