# How to show a vertical rule at the beginning of the current line?

Tags: python, vim, indentation, highlighting

I'm looking for a way in vim to easily visualize the various indent levels of python code. It would help if there was always a vertical rule at the beginning of the current line. That way I can scan down the code to see where the current block ends. Are there any plugins out there that do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply emulate indentation guides.  It's simpler and more effective, in my opinion.  Please, take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim/2166979#2166979) to the [question about indentation guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you could benefit from a plugin that implements [code folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding).

Here is a [tutorial with examples](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/python-and-vim-make-your-own-ide/) (scroll down to "Code folding") that recommends the use of the ["Efficient python folding" plugin for vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494).

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dancingpenguinsoflight.com](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/folded_functions.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

in vim (no plugins needed):

**:set list**

will display tabs as '^I' and EOL as '$' by default.

with

**:set lcs=tab:>>**

you'd set '^I' to '>' (see more on that by :help listchars).

i'm not sure, but there should be another option to set the tab width.

also you may set

**:set autoindent**

for python

Comment: It is recommended to indent Python with 4 spaces, not with tabs.

Comment: @abhijit: you can accomplish what ZyX mentioned by:

:set shiftwidth=4
:set autoindent

use CTRL+T in insert mode

Comment: This was about the fact that most of Python code is indented with spaces, so setting `list` and `lcs` will not show anything. And `expandtab` is maybe better for python.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you're looking for is "colorcolumn", it's new to vim 7.2 or 7.3 I think.

You might be able to work something up with the autocommand trigger CursorMoved

```
autocmd CursorMovedI * set colorcolumn=match(getline("."),"\S")
```

You will probably have to play with this, using intermediate variables and such.

What this would do (if properly buried inside a function), is put a single vertical line at the starting character of the current line. This might be handy, but should probably only be put on a toggle.

EDIT: This turns out to be a bit more complicated than I thought originally. Basically you have to eliminate the effect of literal tabs (if they show up in your file)

```
autocmd CursorMoved * let &colorcolumn=matchend(substitute(getline("."),'\t',repeat(" ",&ts),'g'),"\\S")
```

When I was first putting this together I sortof thought it was silly, but just playing around with it for a few minutes, I sortof like the effect.

Note that you may or may not want a CursorMovedI version.

Comment: You have at least two errors: 1. replace `set colorcolumn` with `let &colorcolumn`: `set` command does not evaluate expressions. 2. Escape backslash in the second argument of match() (or replace double quotes with single).

Answer (score 0):

You can define you own syntax items for it (or use matches). Quick and dirty solution:

```
let colors=["red", "white", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
let matchids=[]
for level in range(1, len(colors))
    execute "hi IndentLevel".level." ctermbg=".colors[level-1]." guibg=".colors[level-1]
    call add(matchids, matchadd('IndentLevel'.level, '^   '.repeat('    ', level-1).'\zs '))
endfor
```

This will highlight five first indentation levels with different colors.

To disable:

```
while !empty(matchids)
    call matchdelete(remove(matchids, 0))
endwhile
```