# Does Vim have indentation guides, Notepad++-style?

Tags: vim, notepad++, indentation, highlight

In Notepad++, there is a dotted line that runs down from the function keyword through the end of the method. It looks like this:

[image: Notepad++ indentation guide example]

Does Vim support something similar?

Answer (score 24):

You can take a look at "Indent Guides : A plugin for visually displaying indent levels in gvim" here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361

Screenshots: [http://nathanaelkane.imgur.com/indent_guides](https://nathanaelkane.imgur.com/indent_guides)

Comment: Cool.  I have a new plugin I need to put on all my machines now.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know, but you can `:set cursorcolumn` to highlight all characters on the same column as your cursor.

To go to the beginning of a function or a scoped block, you can hit `[m` or `[{`, respectively. Then `%` will jump to the other end of the block.

Comment: You may also want to do ":nnoremap <Tab> %" in order to use the more accessible Tab key.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to emulate something like that using match-highlighting.
I have explained the technique in detail in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim/2166979#2166979) to [another
question regarding indentation guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim).

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use tabs for indentation and display them visually with the line

```
"Attention:
"There is an invisible space at the end of the line.
"This space is required.
set list lcs=tab:\|\
```

The plus side of this method is, that you can easily tell tabs and spaces apart.

Personally, I prefer using the unicode center dot character (`set list lcs=tab:\·\`) instead of the pipe symbol, but the pipe symbol is closer to the Notepad++ optic.