# How to get margin indicators (see image) in gvim

Tags: vim, indentation, highlighting

I use this feature in Geany:

[image]

How can I enable it in gvim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display Indentation guides in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim)

Comment: I agree with Randy about possible duplication.  Try my little
[script](https://gist.github.com/734422) at the end of my
[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim/2166979#2166979)
there, or install heavier [Indent
Guides](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361) plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Indent Guides](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361) plugin. It may do what you want.

I personally use [SeeTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=628). It is not suited for persistent indent guides (which I find distracting), but great to selectively toggle on/off to orient yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use Indent Guides plugin with configuration:

`let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 1 \n let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 0 \n autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesOdd  guibg=#ffffff   ctermbg=3 \n autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesEven guibg=#f0f0f0 ctermbg=4`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's there, however

- `:se cursorcolumn`
- folding (e.g. `se fdm=indent`)
- in combination with <kbd>zj</kbd> <kbd>zk</kbd>
- `:he %`

Are probably going to make life easier for you. You see, I always feel that Vi(m) is less about *looking* at the screen and more about 'speaking' in object motions, and this is one area where it seems to show

Comment: cursorcolumn is helpful, but unfortunately it slows down moving of cursor.

Comment: Hey - I never noticed that. Is that with xterm or with gnome/kde vim?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `set listchars=tab:\|\`, with a space after that second backslash (Stack Overflow won't show it).

To show what I mean, a full `listchars` setting might include:

`set listchars=tab:\|\ ,trail:·,extends:…,precedes:…,eol:¬`.

The `|` is a non-ideal but functional solution.

Comment: listchars doesn't work for me because I use spaces for indentation.