# Vim: vertical lines indicating how much a line of code has been indented?

Tags: vim, indentation, highlighting

Is there a way to get Vim to show vertical lines that make it visually easier to see how many tab stops (or spaces) a line of code has been indented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display Indentation guides in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this plugin does what you want.

https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Answer (score 4):

as a start, try this:

```
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·,extends:#
```

see `:help 'listchars'`

You can also place a vertical line at any desired column using (80 in this case):

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

As of vim 7.3, you can use `set colorcolumn=80` (`set cc=80` for short).