# how to draw vertical lines between braces in vim?

Tags: c, vim

How can we have a vertical line shown between the braces in vim editor. It is helpful when I am writing C code.

Upto now, while using vim editor, if i want to know the position of the closing brace, i do following:

1. In normal mode, I take the cursor to opeining brace `{` and then press `%` which take the cursor to closing `}`.
2. And then (try) to remember the line numbers of opening and closing brace.

But when I do this I often forget the line numbers of opening and closing braces. Plus, many times the brace pairs are nested which makes it more confusing to remember.

So I want to have a vertical line drawn between the braces, so that I can do the following:

1. In normal mode, take the cursor to open `{` and press `j` or `k` (or even `%` or any other motion command) to navigate through the file. But with an added line on the left side so that i can know which block I am in.

So, if the code is indented properly, then by looking at the line on the left side I will always have a track of which block I am in. And can use `j` and `k` (or any other motion command) without having to remember the line number of opening and closing brace.

How can we do this in vim ?

Update: Got the answer here [Is it possible to display Indentation guides in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158305/is-it-possible-to-display-indentation-guides-in-vim) .

Comment: Have you tried setting [marks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions) on the open/close braces?  You might also look into the [object motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-motions).

Comment: @kevin Thanks, but does mark draw the line ? I want to have a line on left side. The link you forwarded was difficult to understand, so i thought to ask you this before trying to go through it.

Comment: Why do you need to remember the position ? just test if you press `][` or `]]` you will move to the `}` or `{` . As your code is indent why draw a vertical line, the code does it, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Orel Yea the indented code makes it inherently indented, but I get confused once I move to next pages. I cannot remember `what level of indentation means which block`. So I wanted some sort of line to help me. Found the solution for now (as I only use tab for indentation). This is the command `:set list lcs=tab:\|\ `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The indentLine plugin can help you [image: indentLine plugins] 
https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine (new location)